# Java age approximation from an input

Tags: java, queue

i have this problem about prioritizing by age

these here are the inputs that need processed

```
Dude 20-25 Major Injuries
Guy 48 Panic 
Bob <=4
```

I have to prioritize who must be saved by the age of the victim (young to elder)
as you can see the number/s after the name of the victim are the age

so if it is a range beetwen 20-25 it will be considered as 20

- if it is <=4 it will be considered as 4
- if it is <4 it will be considered as 3
- if it is >4 it will be considered as 5

my question is, What is the best way to process each line so i can get the considered value from the age 
i need to store it back somewhere like in an array or arrayList
so if it was:

```
Dude 20-25 Major Injuries
```

it will change to Dude 20 Major Injuries

i just need the idea to process it, doesnt need to be a code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions and replace the terms by your rules. Here is a small example for the first rule:

```
String input = "Dude 20-25 Major Injuries";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\d]*)([\\d]+)-([\\d]+)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
matcher.matches();
String output = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(4);
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dude 20-25 Major Injuries
Dude 20 Major Injuries
```

Comment: This one really helps, it gives me the idea of what i should use (regular expressions) and it comes with a code example (a working non run-time erroring code :)). Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

To parse the ages, use `String.contains` logic:

```
String input = "Bob 20-25";
Pattern pattern = 
Pattern.compile("[[(<=?)(>=?)]?[0-9]{1, 2}([0-9]{1,2} - [0-9]{1, 2})]");

Matcher matcher = 
pattern.matcher(input);

String regex = matcher.group();
int age = Integer.parseInt(regex);
if (regex.contains("=") {};
else if (regex.contains("<") {
  age = age - 1;
else if (regex.contains(">") {
  age = age + 1;
}
else {}
```

To store the data once you parse the ages, you can use a `PriorityQueue`.

The `PriorityQueue` class provides a constructor where you can specify your own Comparator to order the elements in the Queue. This is the most efficient way to store the elements which will allow for fast retrieval and indexing.

See the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: I think the OP is looking for how to parse the `<=`, `<`, etc.

Comment: I assume these three inputs are not the only ones possible. Using this method would result in you needing ~300 `if` statements to make it generic enough to use.

Comment: Why -1? I made the edit to consider the other ages not >=, <=, <, > 4 and 20 - 25

Comment: Someone probably gave you -1 because your code *only* handles the exact `<=4` and `20-25` cases, and otherwise just parses the int. What if the input is `30-35`, or `>50`. Or in case of `15-20` you would yield `20` (it contains "20"), but it should be `15`. It's no general solution at all.

Comment: I believe I fixed this now using regular expressions. Let me know guys.